# Selecting leftmost unique elements from multiple lists until given size is reached

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have the following lists:

```py
a = [ 1,  6, 76, 15, 46, 55, 47, 15, 72, 58, ..] # there could be more than 10 elements in each
b = [17, 48, 22,  7, 35, 19, 91, 85, 49, 35, ..]
c = [46,  8, 53, 49, 28, 82, 30, 86, 57,  9, ..]
d = [82, 12, 24, 60, 66, 17, 13, 69, 28, 99, ..]
e = [ 1, 53, 17, 82, 21, 20, 88, 10, 82, 41, ..]
```

I want to write a function which takes any number of those list (could be all, could be only `a` and `c` for example) as its argument and selects the leftmost unique 10 elements  equally from every list. For example, I will show in pictures with.

The initial data we have (length of 10 assumption).
[image]

We look at the first elements of every row and see `a` and `e` have same values. We randomly select let's say `e`, remove that element and shift it to the left and get this

[image]

Here we see that there is again overlap, 17 is appearing already and we shift `e` one more time

[image]

Again similar problem and we shift it one last time

[image]

Finally, we can select the first two elements of each list and there will be no duplicates

```
[1, 6, 17, 48, 46, 8, 82, 12, 21, 53]
```

It could be that more than one list could have identical values, same rules should apply.

I came with this which and for solving randomness I decided to shuffle the list before using it:

```py
def prepare_unique_array(
    arrays: list = [], 
    max_length: int = 10, 
    slice_number: int = 2
):
    unique_array = []

    for array in arrays:
        for i in range(slice_number):
            while not len(unique_array) == max_length:
                if array[i] not in unique_array:
                    unique_array.append(array[i])
                else:
                    while array[i+1] in unique_array:
                        i += 1
                    unique_array.append(array[i+1])

    return unique_array
```

Which gives the desired result given those initial values, but anything changes and it does not work.

maybe there is a numpy approach which does it faster and easier as well.

I will appreciate any guide/help

Comment: Why at step 2 (removing 17), you don't remove the 17 in row `d`?

Comment: Because I am concerned about the leftmost elements and as the goal is to select 10 equally, it is the first two elements of each. 17 on D does not qualify. If for some reason we should have to shift D as well and 17 appeared in first two positions, then yes randomly one of the 17ths would be gone

Comment: Can you give an example where your code "doesn't work"? How does it not work, exactly? Does it return a wrong value? Does it crash with an error message?

Comment: How do you verify that the output of your function was in fact derived in the correct manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cycle` and `iter` to pick one element from each iterable, alternately:

```py
from itertools import cycle

def uniques_evenly(n, *iterables):
    its = cycle(iter(seq) for seq in iterables)
    seen = set()
    it = next(its)
    for _ in range(n):
        x = next(it)
        while x in seen:
            x = next(it)  # pick next unique number
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
        it = next(its)    # switch to next iterator
```

Note that this will crash if one of the iterators is too short.

Testing:

```py
a = [ 1,  6, 76, 15, 46, 55, 47, 15, 72, 58, 37756, 712, 666]
b = [17, 48, 22,  7, 35, 19, 91, 85, 49, 35, 42]
c = [46,  8, 53, 49, 28, 82, 30, 86, 57,  9]
d = [82, 12, 24, 60, 66, 17, 13, 69, 28, 99]
e = [ 1, 53, 17, 82, 21, 20, 88, 10, 82, 41, 216]

print( list(uniques_evenly(10, a,b,c,d,e)) )
# [1, 17, 46, 82, 53, 6, 48, 8, 12, 21]
```

### Explanations

We use `iter()` to transform a list into an iterator. An iterator is something that "consumes" values and returns them, at every call of `next()`. For instance:

```py
l = [3, 4, 7]  # l is a list
i = iter(l)       # i is an iterator

print( next(i) )
# 3
print( next(i) )
# 4
print( next(i) )
# 7
print( next(i) )
# raises exception StopIteration
```

Then, we use `itertools.cycle` to alternate between the five iterators. `cycle` returns an infinite iterator that cycles between the items in the list we gave it. We gave it a list of five iterators:

```py
its = cycle(iter(seq) for seq in iterables)
```

This is the same thing as if we had written:

```py
its = cycle([iter(a), iter(b), iter(c), iter(d), iter(e)]
```

Here is a demonstration with only two iterators instead of 5:

```py
a = ['hello', 'world']
b = [5, 12]
its = cycle([iter(a), iter(b)])

it = next(its)     # it is now the iterator on a
print( next(it) )  # 'hello'
it = next(its)     # it is now the iterator on b
print( next(it) )  # 5
it = next(its)     # it cycles back to a
print( next(it) )  # 'world'
it = next(its)     # it is now b
print( next(it) )  # 12
it = next(its)     # it is a
print( next(it) )  # raises exception StopIteration
```

So this is essentially what happens in `uniques_evenly`.

In addition, we use a set `seen` to remember the elements we have already seen. Sets are cool because testing for membership is a fast operation: `if x in seen:` is a constant-time operation, it doesn't matter how big `seen` is.

Now `it` is one of the five iterators, say the iterator on list `d`. We pick the next element in `d` with `x = next(it)`; then we run the loop:

```py
while x in seen:
    x = next(it)
```

Which means: if `x` is an element already seen previously, then pick the next element in `d`. Keep picking the next element until you find an element that wasn't seen previously. Once we've finally picked an element `x` that hasn't been seen previously, we add it to set `seen` so it won't be picked again in the future, and then:

```py
yield x
```

This is a bit special. It means `uniques_evenly` is not a function; if it was a function, we would have used the keyword `return` and not `yield`. Instead, `uniques_evenly` is a generator. Instead of using this syntax with `yield`, the other alternative would have been to declare a list `result`, initially empty, then instead of `yield x`, I would have written `result.append(x)`; then at the very end of the function, `return result`. Then `uniques_evenly` would have been a function that returns a list.

The difference between a function that returns a list, and a generator, is a bit subtle. Basically a generator behaves like a lazy list, whose elements are computed and produced only when needed.

When testing my code, I immediately converted the generator to a list anyway:

```py
print( list(uniques_evenly(10, a,b,c,d,e)) )
```

So the difference doesn't matter. If you're more comfortable with having a variable `result` and using `result.append(x)` instead of `yield x`, then returning `result` at the end of the function, you can do it this way instead.

Comment: I am still trying to comprehend this, thank you. Is it possible to add randomness to this code as well? when identical elements randomly keep one and shift the other. I presume, in this code randomness does not exist. One could shuffle the orders of the lists, but it would not make the shifting decision over the second elements of the lists random

Comment: @EmilMirzayev I suppose you could replace the set `seen` by a dict `seen_dict` that instead of just remembering the seen elements, remembers the seen elements and maps them to the iterator they're from. Then, instead of `x = next(it)` in the inner while loop, use `x = next(random.choice([it, seen_dict[x]]))`. And instead of `seen.add(x)`, use `seen[x] = it`.

Comment: thank you! Could you add some more comments to your code so that I comprehend it a bit better? I can not use debug tools that well, but I want to understand the steps of the process. Thank you

Comment: @EmilMirzayev I added a few explanations.